# ffmpeg trim Unable to find a suitable output format

Tags: android, kotlin, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

As stated in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/686621/how-to-use-slow-motion-effect-in-a-specific-time-interval-with-ffmpeg) i try to split a video using mmpeg, slow down one of the parts and merge them back together.

I use the [SSffmpegVideoOperation](https://github.com/SimformSolutionsPvtLtd/SSffmpegVideoOperation) libary for convenient ffmpeg interactions.

I adapted the slow motion function such that it has a start and end point and now returns the following query

```
val inputs: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
inputs.apply {
    add("-i")
    add(inputVideo)
    add("-filter_complex")
    add("[0:v]trim=0:$startSeconds,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]")
    add("[0:v]trim=$startSeconds:$endSeconds,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]")
    add("[0:v]trim=start=$endSeconds,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]")
    add("[v1]setpts=${setpts}*PTS[slowv]")
    add("[v1][v2][v3]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out]")
    add("-map")
    add("[out]")
    add(output)
}
```

where `input` and `output` are valid file paths and `startSeconds` and `endSeconds` are Integer values.

But for almost every line expect for the first line with trim i get an error.
For example:

```
[NULL @ 0xb40000781a868290] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[0:v]trim=5:10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]'
    [0:v]trim=5:10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]: Invalid argument
```

i tried a lot but cannot find any reason for this.

Comment: All the filters after `-filter_complex` applies one FFmpeg argument. Instead of add add add... , use only one `add` with a long string.

Comment: Add `;` between them as used by command line.

Comment: @Rotem id did it in separat lines since all other actions of this library did it the same way. but this really solved my problem. THANK YOU